# Пытаюсь приравнять общую сумму записей в соотвествующх полях двух таблиц, сгруппировав по другому полю. Но запрос неправильно работает

Tags: sql, sql-server

Даны 2 таблицы - `DepoSevkDetay` и `SatisDetay`. В них обоих есть поля `UrunID`, `Miktar`. Но значения Миктар не совпадают. Нужно приравнять общую сумму `Miktar` в `DepoSevkDetay` к общей сумме `Miktar` в `SatisDetay`. (Обновить `DepoSevkDetay` из `SatisDetay`). Следующий запрос неправильно работает, что не так? Учитывая что количество записей для каждого Урунайди в 2 таблицах не совпадает

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.[Miktar] = (((Table_B.Miktar)/Table_C.c) + 
(case when ((Table_B.Miktar) % Table_C.c  < Table_C.r) then 1 
                                                        else 0 end ))
FROM
    [Retail].[dbo].[tb_DepoSevkDetay] AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT SUM(Miktar)as Miktar, UrunID
                FROM tb_SatisDetay
                GROUP BY UrunID ) AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.[UrunID] = Table_B.[UrunID]
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT COUNT([UrunID]) AS c, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UrunID) r, UrunID as UrunID
                FROM tb_DepoSevkDetay
                GROUP BY UrunID ) AS Table_C 
        ON Table_B.[UrunID] = Table_C.[UrunID]
```